# Carga de datos en listview lenta

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Recibo 500 rows del select a la tabla facturas con sqlite, y me tarda un minuto y medio, me parece una barbaridad de tiempo.
¿Debería de realizar un paginado o no? Ya que es lo único que se me ha ocurrido.

**Este es el método donde realizo la consulta**

private ArrayList obtenerFacturasCliente() {

```
    ArrayList<FacturasCabeceras> data = new ArrayList<FacturasCabeceras>();

    TestAdapter mDbHelper = g.getDB();

    // Aqui lo que hacemos es pasar el int fecfra a date para ordenarlo posteriormente.
    // Y los substring para desglosar los datos y montarlo para pasarlo a date.
    String sql = "SELECT *, DATE(" +
            "SUBSTRING(CAST(fecfra AS CHAR(8)), 4, 4 )," +
            "SUBSTRING(CAST(fecfra AS CHAR(8)), 2, 2 )," +
            "SUBSTRING(CAST(fecfra AS CHAR(8)), 0, 2)) as fecha " +
            "FROM facturas WHERE numcli = " + idCliente + " GROUP BY numfac ORDER BY fecha DESC";

    Cursor c = mDbHelper.getDB().rawQuery(sql, null);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ITALY));

    // hacer el sumatorio
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            FacturasCabeceras f = new FacturasCabeceras();
            f.idCliente = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("numcli"));
            f.numPedido = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("numped"));
            f.numFactura = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("numfac"));
            f.numAlbaran = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("numalb"));
            f.fecha = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("fecfra"));

            //total
            f.tot = df.format(new BigDecimal((double) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(obtenerTotal(f.numFactura, idCliente)) * 1000) / 1000)) + " €";


            if (f.fecha.length() < 6) {
                f.fecha = "0" + f.fecha;
            }
            f.fecha = f.fecha.substring(0, 2) + "/" + f.fecha.substring(2, 4) + "/" + "20" + f.fecha.substring(4, 6);


            data.add(f);

        } while (c.moveToNext());

    }
    c.close();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Puede que la latencia con la base de datos sea alta. Además, para mayor rendimiento se recomienda usar RecyclerView en lugar de ListView.

Answer (score 0):

La forma más rápida para iterar solbre los valores de un cursor

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    ...
}
```

por lo tanto realiza el cambio a :

```
private ArrayList obtenerFacturasCliente() {

    ArrayList<FacturasCabeceras> data = new ArrayList<FacturasCabeceras>();

    TestAdapter mDbHelper = g.getDB();

    // Aqui lo que hacemos es pasar el int fecfra a date para ordenarlo posteriormente.
    // Y los substring para desglosar los datos y montarlo para pasarlo a date.
    String sql = "SELECT *, DATE(" +
            "SUBSTRING(CAST(fecfra AS CHAR(8)), 4, 4 )," +
            "SUBSTRING(CAST(fecfra AS CHAR(8)), 2, 2 )," +
            "SUBSTRING(CAST(fecfra AS CHAR(8)), 0, 2)) as fecha " +
            "FROM facturas WHERE numcli = " + idCliente + " GROUP BY numfac ORDER BY fecha DESC";

    Cursor c = mDbHelper.getDB().rawQuery(sql, null);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ITALY));


while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
 FacturasCabeceras f = new FacturasCabeceras();
            f.idCliente = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("numcli"));
            f.numPedido = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("numped"));
            f.numFactura = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("numfac"));
            f.numAlbaran = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("numalb"));
            f.fecha = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("fecfra"));

            //total
            f.tot = df.format(new BigDecimal((double) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(obtenerTotal(f.numFactura, idCliente)) * 1000) / 1000)) + " €";


            if (f.fecha.length() < 6) {
                f.fecha = "0" + f.fecha;
            }
            f.fecha = f.fecha.substring(0, 2) + "/" + f.fecha.substring(2, 4) + "/" + "20" + f.fecha.substring(4, 6);


            data.add(f);
  }
 c.close();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Nada me sigue durando lo mismo, voy a probar a cambiar el ListView por el Recycler como me dijo Mateo, muchas gracias.